# How do I print this in C?

Tags: c, printf, getchar

Hi I'm relatively new to programming so please bear with me.

I would like to make a program that takes the input `bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy` and outputs

```
else if (c == 'x')
     ++nx;
```

where x is a letter of the input, and where the output is repeated for each letter of the input.

This is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        printf("else if (c == '%d')\n", c);
        printf("\t++n%d;\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of returning the output I want, the output is

```
else if (c == '98')
    ++n98;
else if (c == '99')
    ++n99;
else if (c == '100')
    ++n100;
else if (c == '101')
    ++n101;
else if (c == '102')
    ++n102;
...
```

Why is `c` not working as a variable?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `'%d'` should be `'%c'`.

Comment: If you are writing a program that writes another program, you'd better have a really good reason. This feels like you have some other underlying design issue that needs handling.

Comment: You also could make your code a lot more readable using a `switch` statement rather than a series of `if-else`'s.

Comment: @Andrew I'm trying to write the program for exercise 1-14 of Kernighan and Ritchie's The C Programming Language, which asks for a histogram of the frequency of each character in the input, and I figured I could write a program for the else if statement of each letter of the alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing in C and printing a string pointed by format to stdout you'll need to make sure you're using the right format specifiers. This will ensure that your argument is formatted correctly and inserted into the resulting string as you would expect.

In your case, you need to use `%c`. However, you have `%d` currently, which is the equivalent to `%i` for integers. You can google more on format specifiers to learn more about other options as well.

Here's an interesting read on the subject:

http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Answer (score 3):

You want `c == '%c'` to compare by character or `c == %d` (without the single quotes) to compare by ordinal value, but you should really learn to use arrays.  It looks like you are trying to code something the hard way, and use a code generator to save you some typing.  Instead:

```
 int n[256] = {0};  /* storage for counters, initialized to zero */
```

and:

```
n[c]++;  // increment the counter for character c;
```

You're code will be much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You used `%d` in your printf but `%d` if for integers. You want to print a char so it should be `%c`.
Replace `%d` by `%c`

More on this link: http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/format.html

Comment: Both `c` and `d` are for `int`. The difference is in how they are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

char c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("else if (c == '%c')\n", c);
    printf("\t++n%c;\n", c);
}

return 0;
}
```

what you want is characters not ints

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
printf("else if (c == '%c')\n", c);
printf("\t++n%c;\n", c);
```

See [printf specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

The %d specifier is for intergers